# How to use a Javascript Function to name Variables?

Tags: javascript, variables

I'd like to be able to create variables using a function, something like:

```
function createVar(a,b){
    var [a]name[b];
}
```

So if I call the function `createVar(prefix,suffix)` I'd end up with a variable named `prefixnamesuffix`.

Comment: You can always create on-the-fly variable in JS, why you want a function?

Comment: Why do you need to have variably-named variables? Generally it's much easier to use the hash-style access you can get from a bare object

Comment: Do not be sorry about asking seemingly basic question. If you are in need of asking, others too most likely will be interested. It's only frowned upon if you ask poorly or if your question shows no sign of effort to explain the matter. So don't do that self-deprecating dance, and ask your question right away.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't create a local variable that way, but you can create properties with strings.

```
function createVar(obj, a, b)
{
   obj[a+'name'+b] = foo;
}
```

Comment: beat me by a hair. I'd just add that you can also create global variables by attaching properties to the `window` object: `window[a+'name'+b]`

Comment: Absolutely perfect! My script is working now. Thanks to both of you for your incredibly fast help.

Comment: If the solution works, I'm sure Daniel would appreciate having his answer accepted.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, it's probably obvious but this is my first post here. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 1):

```
function createVar(a, b, value) {
    // declare the variable on current context(default is window),
    // and set value, default is undefined
    this[a + 'name' + b] = value;
}
```

use as:

```
createVar('a', 'b');
// variable anameb now is declare, but it's value is undefined
console.log(anameb); // -> undefined

createVar('prefix', 'suffix', 'optional');
// variable prefixnamesuffix now is exist in window
console.log(prefixnamesuffix); // -> 'optional'
```

or:

```
var obj = {};
createVar.call(obj, 'pre', 'suf', 'defValue');
// variable prenamesuf is now exist in obj, but not exist in window
console.log(obj.prenamesuf); // -> 'defValue'
console.log(prenamesuf); // ReferenceError: prenamesuf is not defined
```

Answer (score 0):

This IS possible - sort of as it IS a bit tricky.

This all begins by understanding the scope of a variable.  Let's look at a basic, simple example:

```
var myvar = 'I see';
```

This creates a varaible, at a basic level named `myvar` that you can access such as `alert(myvar);` which will, in this case alert "I see".

What this really does is create a property on the window object. Thus, `var myvar = 'I see';` is the same as `window['myvar'] = 'I see';`.

Complex objects can also be created in this manner.

Some more examples:

```
window['fred'] = 'howdy fred';// create fred property
var regularfred = 'howdy fred'; // create regularfred property
window['town'] = {}; // create town object
window['town']['george'] = 'georgetown'; //create town.george property
alert(fred + ":" + regularfred); // alerts "howdy fred:howdy fred"
alert(fred == regularfred);// alerts true
alert(this['town']['george']);// alerts "georgetown"

function createvar(a, b) {
    this[a + 'name' + b] = "fredling";
    alert(this[a + 'name' + b]);// alerts "fredling"
    alert(window[a + 'name' + b]);// alerts "fredling"
}
var hi = 'hi';
var lo = 'loook';
createvar(hi, lo);
alert(this[hi + 'name' + lo]);// alerts "fredling"
```

Requisit working example on this: http://jsfiddle.net/pGWZN/

Comment: I know this is SORT of a duplicate answer but it details the specifics of the window object properties.